# I want to set loading animation to ng-select drop down in angular (only for dropdown not for input field)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, animation

Here are my html code and .ts code.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-branch',
  templateUrl: './branch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./branch.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('myAnimationTrigger', [
      state('void', style({ opacity: 0 })),
      transition(':enter, :leave', [
        animate('1s ease-in-out', style({opacity :1}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class BranchComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('@myAnimationTrigger') myAnimation = true;
```

```html
                <div>
                  <ng-select
                    [items]="branches"
                    (change) = "branchClear()"
                    bindLabel="name"
                    autofocus
                    placeholder="select branch"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedBranch">
                    <ng-template #optionTemplate let-item="item" myAnimation>
                      <div class="option">
                        <div class="option-details">
                          {{item.name}}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </ng-template>
                  </ng-select>
                </div>
```

in these case animation set to both input field and dropdown both. How I apply animation only for dropdown?

Answer (score -1):

Reading the ng-select documentation I found out exist an input called **loading**. This one will help you showing a default loading icon depending of the status it has.
Now, they allow you to customize this animation passing it into the html with an specific syntax as showed below.

I will attach the link code with their example. I hope can help you!

[image: Example Custom Loading Code]

[Template Loading Custom Example](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/demo/app/examples/template-loading-example/template-loading-example.component.html)